# If w is not in span($u,v$) and $v$ is not in span($u$), are {$u,v,w$} linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let u, v, w be vectors in $R^4$. Suppose that w is not in span($u, v$) and $v$ is not in span($u$) and $u$ /= 0. Are {$u, v, w$} linearly independent? (Give a proof or a counterexample.)

Unsure how to tackle this one. I think its true but its the proof part I'm unsure what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there are scalars $a, b, c$ such that $au+bv+cw=0$.  If $c\neq 0$, then $w$ can be written as a linear combination of $u$ and $v$, so $w$ would be in their span; contradiction.  So $c=0$ and we have $au+bv =0$.  If $b\neq 0$, then similarly, $v$ is in the span of $u$.  Contradiction, so $b=0$.  Then we have $au=0$, and since $u\neq 0$, we must have $a=0$.  Since $a=b=c=0$, the vectors ar linearly independent.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Thank you very much!